# Does TestCafe execute test steps, in 'test', asynchronously and not sequential?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am working on an automation project and we follow that age old model of a test case being a list of test steps to validate a behavior in the application under test. Each test step exists in a class with the associated assertions. My problem is the test itself is calling the steps out of order. I know this because inserted hard waits in-between each step and they executed in the correct order and the failed step is caught.

Example:

```
test
  .page(page)('Submit Button Behaviors', async () => {
    await t.addRequestHooks(mocks.consent(url));
    await t.addRequestHooks(mocks.sc(url));
    await t.wait(1000);
    consentPageSteps.verify_the_header_is_displayed();
    await t.wait(1000);
    consentPageSteps.verify_the_previous_button_is_displayed();
    await t.wait(1000);
    consentPageSteps.verify_user_can_select_all_consent_checkboxes();
    await t.wait(1000);
    consentPageSteps.verify_the_consent_submit_button_is_active();
    await t.wait(1000);
    consentPageSteps.verify_user_can_deselect_all_consent_checkboxes();
    await t.wait(1000);
    consentPageSteps.verify_the_consent_submit_button_is_disabled();
    await t.wait(1000);
  });
```

with the waits:

Running tests in:

- Chrome 111.0.0.0 / Windows 10

Consent Page
verify_the_equipment_header_is_displayed        =>       true
verify_the_previous_button_is_displayed         =>       true
verify_user_can_select_all_consent_checkboxes
verify_the_consent_submit_button_is_active      =>       false
verify_user_can_deselect_all_consent_checkboxes
verify_user_can_select_all_consent_checkboxes

× Self Service - Submit Button Behaviors

1. AssertionError: verify_the_consent_submit_button_is_active did not resolve to true: expected false to be truthy

(Note, the test fails as expected)

without the waits:

Consent Page
verify_user_can_select_all_consent_checkboxes
verify_user_can_deselect_all_consent_checkboxes
verify_user_can_select_all_consent_checkboxes
verify_the_consent_submit_button_is_disabled    =>       true
verify_the_equipment_header_is_displayed        =>       true
verify_the_consent_submit_button_is_active      =>       false
verify_the_previous_button_is_displayed         =>       true

√ Self Service - Submit Button Behaviors

Steps are out of order and the 'false' step is not failing.

Can someone help me understand what is happening?

Comment: Please share the used methods of consentPageSteps. We cannot determine the cause without their content. Perhaps these methods are `async`. In this case, you need to execute them with `await`.

Comment: Yes, the statements are missing the 'awaits'

Answer (score 1):

I am going to leave this up with great embarrassment to be filed under "coding after 10 hours with crossed-eyes leads to stupid mistakes". I forgot the 'awaits' in front of each ConsentPageSteps statement. Once I looked at the code this morning and saw my mistake - I am embarrassed. I added the awaits and the script is running fine now.

So, I am leaving this here for other automation engineers as a learning experience.